# Tesseract OCR Pitch Text

Tags: ocr, tesseract, pitch

I have a question about some terminology when it comes to optical character recognition software, specifically the Tesseract OCR engine.

I am reading an article on the Tesseract OCR engine, and it frequently mentions something called `Fixed pitch text`, and I am not entirely sure what that means. I am assuming pitch is the space that a line of text occupies, but that does not really make sense in the context of the article I am reading.

This is a sentence from the article that uses this wording:

> Blobs are organized into text lines, and the lines and regions are analyzed for fixed pitch or proportional text.

I have looked online for some definition of this, but most articles on OCR just use it with no explanation. I am guessing this means it is a pretty simple/common term.

If anybody cares, the article I am reading is called "An Overview of the Tesseract OCR Engine", written by Ray Smith.

Comment: I think "fixed pitch" means "monospaced characters", where each character has a fixed length. On the other hand, in "proportional text", each character occupies only as much width as it needs. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font

Answer (score 1):

When first trying to find text in an image, Tesseract will identify possible regions where the text is present with blobs. Once possible regions where text could be present have been identified, Tesseract then looks to see if those regions contain "fixed pitch." Basically, this means that it's trying to figure out if the regions that it found earlier actually contain text. The fixed pitch is the different types of vectors that are used to create a certain letter or word, and Tesseract looks for those to analyze what letter or word it is looking at in an image.

Comment: No problem, happy to help!